Nuxt 3 Supabase - 500 auth Session missing
I am trying to integrate Supabase Github OAuth with Nuxt 3 but I am having an error "500 auth session missing" and it's very slow!

The server middleware causing the Error: (user.ts)
import { serverSupabaseUser } from "#supabase/server";
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  event.context.user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
});

I am passing the cookies from the client to server.
You can check the Code here:
https://github.com/mohamed-ali-masmoudi/supa-nuxt-500
Or
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/mohamed-ali-masmoudi/supa-nuxt-500 (just reload the page if you get 404)
You just need to add SUPABASE_URL and SUPABASE_KEY to .env
Thanks

Hey any luck @Daly? I got same issue.

Hey @AdamOrłowski, yes. Check my comment here: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/supabase/issues/388#issuecomment-2245250514

The problem is that Nuxt executes the files under "/server/middleware" on every request for all the routes also for "/" where in our case the user is not logged yet.
Here are two other potential workarounds:
1- Set a list for the protected routes (that should include the user)
import { serverSupabaseUser } from '#supabase/server';
const protectedRoutes = [
  "/api/admin",
  "/api/user"
]
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const url = event.node.req.url
  if(protectedRoutes.some(route => url?.includes(route)) ) {
    console.log("Auth needed: ", event.node.req.url)
    try {
      const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
      if (user) {
        event.context.user = user;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.info(' #####  Auth error #####');
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log("No Auth needed: ", event.node.req.url)
  }
});
2- Just make it non blocking by catching the error

import { serverSupabaseUser, serverSupabaseClient } from "#supabase/server";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
  const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
  event.context.user = user;
  } catch (error) {
  console.error("Auth error: ", error);
  }
});

2- Just make it non blocking by catching the error
import { serverSupabaseUser, serverSupabaseClient } from "#supabase/server";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
  const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);
  event.context.user = user;
  } catch (error) {
  console.error("Auth error: ", error);
  }
});


I have solved it differently but it's a good inside. Thanks @Daly!
